# HTML/CSS drop down menu, want to make it's background a fixed width

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm using an HTML/CSS menu from the article [SuckerFish Dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/).  My particular menu has a grey background.  I am trying to get the menu's background to have a fixed width.  I tried adding a width parameter to the #navbar section in the CSS but that didn't seem to do anything.  How do I get this fixed width behavior?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <!-- The strange spacing herein prevents an IE6 whitespace bug. -->
    <li><a href="index.html">System Set-Up &amp; Status</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">NMEA Output</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="ch1.html">Channel 1</a></li><li>
                <a href="ch2.html">Channel 2</a></li><li>
                <a href="ch3.html">Channel 3</a></li><li>
                <a href="ch4.html">Channel 4</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">UDP Output</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="udpch1.html">Channel 1</a></li><li>
                <a href="udpch2.html">Channel 2</a></li><li>
                <a href="udpch3.html">Channel 3</a></li><li>
                <a href="udpch4.html">Channel 4</a></li><li></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="baro.html">Baro / PoE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="advanced.html">Advanced</a>
        </li>
    <li><a href="mob.html">MOB</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1em; }
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left; }
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none; }
#navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #999999; }
#navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 10em; /* Width to help Opera out */
    background-color: #69f;}
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
    float: none; }
#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #000; }
#navbar li li a:hover {
    background-color: #999999; }
```

The [CSS snippet is here](http://resplendid.com/tmp/navbar.css) and the [HTML snippet is here](http://resplendid.com/tmp/navbar.html)

[jsfiddle of question](http://jsfiddle.net/sbagdat/PT79t/):

Comment: Don't link to code, make sure it is in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#navbar` is taking the appropriate width, but it does not have a `background-color` set so by default it is transparent.

Remove `background-color` from `#navbar li a` and add it to `#navbar` instead. You will also have to remove the height and clear your floats for it to work properly:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    /*clear floats */
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/UfuG2/**

Answer (score 1):

Since you're floating your menu list items, you'll want to put a clearfix on the unordered list. Then you can set the width and background-color on the ul. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/qT7xs/.